# How to refactor java codes which prepare variable length of args and call a method?

Tags: java, refactoring

I have a .java file in which many methods like the following code exists, how can I refactor to make it cleaner?

```
public static void e(Throwable tr) {
    if (!debug) {
        return;
    }
    if (!allowE) return;
    if (tr == null) {
        return;
    }
    String content = wrapContent(tr.getMessage());
    StackTraceElement caller = getCallerStackTraceElement();
    String tag = generateTag(caller);

    customLogger.e(tag, content, tr);
}

public static void i(String content) {
    if (!debug) {
        return;
    }
    if (!allowI) return;
    content = wrapContent(content);
    StackTraceElement caller = getCallerStackTraceElement();
    String tag = generateTag(caller);

    customLogger.i(tag, content);
}
```

========update======

This class is a wrapper of android.util.Log, for guys suggesting to follow naming conventions :).

Comment: Give names with more than one letter to the methods?

Comment: You can change the method names to something that makes sense.

Comment: You could use generics...

Comment: You could use a `Map`, keyed to the object type which returns a `boolean` instead of `allowE` and `allowI`...

Comment: Try to follow **naming conventions** in java described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Technically, `e` can call `i`, it passing `tr.getMessage()` as the parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can strip most of the code into a shared method and then call that from both places.

```
public static voidcombined(String content, Throwable tr, bool allow)
{
    if (!debug) return;
    if (!allow) return;
    content = wrapContent(content);
    StackTraceElement caller = getCallerStackTraceElement();
    String tag = generateTag(caller);
    if (tr != null) {
        customLogger.e(tag, content, tr);
    } else {
        customLogger.i(tag, content);
    }
}

public static void e(Throwable tr) {
    if (tr == null) {
        return;
    }
    combined(tr.getMessage(), tr, allowE);
}

public static void i(String content) {
    combined(content, null, allowI);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (!debug) {
        return;
    }
    if (!allowE) return;
```

appears twice, we can put it into a method `isAllow()`

```
String content = wrapContent(tr.getMessage());
StackTraceElement caller = getCallerStackTraceElement();
String tag = generateTag(caller);
```

appears twice too, and customLogger.e and customLogger.i is very alike. Lets put it into method  `logInLevel`().

So, like this:

```
    public static void e(Throwable tr) {
        if (!isAllow()||tr==null) return ;
        logInLevel(ERROR,tr.getMessage())
    }

    public static void i(String content) {
        if (!isAllow()) return ;
        logInLevel(INFO,content);
    }

    private static boolean isAllow(){
         return debug&&allowE;
     }

    private static logInLevel(int level, String content){
        StackTraceElement caller = getCallerStackTraceElement();
        String tag = generateTag(caller);
        if(level==INFO){
            customLogger.i(tag, content);
        }
        else{//ERROR , you may add more log level here
            customLogger.e(tag, content);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to apply the separation of concern design principle, to make sure that distinct section of your code are addressing specific concerns.

```
/**
 * Logs error message 
 * @param tr a {@link Throwable} object containing the message to log
 */
public static void logErrorMessage(Throwable tr) {
    if (tr == null) {
        return;
    }
    logContent(tr.getMessage(), allowE, debug, LogLevel.ERROR);
}

/**
 * Logs message
 * @param content the message to log
 * @param allow some variable 
 * @param debug check the debug status 
 * @param ll message log level 
 */
public static void logContent(String content, boolean allow, boolean debug , LogLevel ll) {
    if (!debug) || !allow) return;
    switch(ll) {
    case ERROR:
        customLogger.e(getTag(content), content);
        break;
    case INFO:
        customLogger.i(getTag(content), content);
        break;
    default:
    }

}

/**
 * Generates tag 
 * @param content the message to log
 * @return a tagged string
 */
public static String getTag(String content) {
    content = wrapContent(content);
    return  generateTag(getCallerStackTraceElement());
}
```